# MySQL Nested Select Referencing Outside Table?

Tags: mysql

I have this query:

```
SELECT
    course_category.id      AS languageId,
    course_category.code    AS languageCode,
    course_category.name    AS languageName,
    (
        SELECT
            SUM(gradebook_result.score)
        FROM
            gradebook_result
        JOIN
            gradebook_evaluation ON  gradebook_evaluation.id=gradebook_result.evaluation_id
        JOIN
            gradebook_category ON gradebook_category.id=gradebook_evaluation.category_id
        WHERE
            gradebook_category.course_code=course_category.code

    ) AS languageWordsTranslated
FROM
    course_category
WHERE
    course_category.code != 'GEN'
ORDER BY
    name
ASC
```

The problem occurs inside the nested SELECT where I get an error referencing the course_category table from within the SELECT on line:

```
WHERE
    gradebook_category.course_code=course_category.code
```

Giving error:

```
Unknown column 'course_category.code' in 'where clause'
```

I have done this query before with other projects the only difference is that this one has joins within it. Any ideas?

EDIT: I removed the joins and hardcoded:

```
WHERE
    course_category.code = 'ARA'
```

Seems like the joins mess it up, any way to fix that??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to do it a bit different way, using subquery and joining to it:

```
SELECT
    course_category.id      AS languageId,
    course_category.code    AS languageCode,
    course_category.name    AS languageName,
    t.total AS languageWordsTranslated
FROM
    course_category
JOIN (
    SELECT gradebook_category.course_code, SUM(gradebook_result.score) as total
    FROM gradebook_result
    JOIN gradebook_evaluation ON  gradebook_evaluation.id=gradebook_result.evaluation_id
    JOIN gradebook_category ON gradebook_category.id=gradebook_evaluation.category_id
    GROUP BY gradebook_category.course_code
) t ON t.course_code = course_category.code
WHERE
    course_category.code != 'GEN'
ORDER BY
    name
ASC
```

Comment: Error: Unknown column 'course_category.code' in 'group statement'. Never seen it done that way before.

Comment: @user622469 try once again, I've just corrected the code. You were quicker :-).

Comment: Scratch that, im getting confused with my tables. One moment!

Comment: @user622469 What does return subquery itself (part between `JOIN (` and `) t ON`)? Are `course_code`s from subquery in column `code` from table `course_category`?

Comment: Your query returned nothing because I joined the wrong table, after replacing the right one I got the results! Thank you. May I ask one more thing, why do your approach vs. mine?

Comment: @user622469 generally I don't like correlated subqueries, they are usually (but probably not always it may depends) slower (because are executed once for each row).